# Incorrect syntax near 'GO' using SqlCommand

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlcommand

This interface appears every time I execute this code that you find below :

```
str1 = "USE [" + database + "];" + vbCrLf +
   "GO" + vbCrLf +
   " CREATE TABLE  [dbo].[ARMSet] ([Id] Int IDENTITY(1, 1) Not NULL,

    );" + vbCrLf +
              " GO"
Dim myCommand1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str1, myConn)
```

And the description of the bug is :

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Comment: To be fair, there's [a lot of posts about T-SQL and the `GO` command](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=t-sql+go+command).

Comment: You'd be better off with a `Using  myCommand1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str1, myConn)` ... `End Using` there if you're going to have multiple statements between the creation and destruction of the command object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Answer (score 4):

Rather than forcing the server to parse your `USE` statement, and then keep the command/connection around to recycle for sending the `CREATE TABLE`, having split your two statements apart because, as [MatSnow says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60391121/15498), `GO` isn't a SQL Server command.

You could instead just call [`ChangeDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ChangeDatabase_System_String_) on `myConn` before using it:

```
   myConn.ChangeDatabase(database)
   str1 = "CREATE TABLE  [dbo].[ARMSet] (
               [Id] Int IDENTITY(1, 1) Not NULL,
               [Name] nvarchar(max)  Not NULL,
               [ArmNumber] Int  Not NULL,
               [IP] nvarchar(max)  Not NULL,
               [Port] Int  Not NULL,
               [Modbusaddress] Int  Not NULL,
               [Type] Int  Not NULL,
               [IsMaster] bit  Not NULL,
               [DeliveryType] Int  Not NULL,
               [CurretPosition] Int  Not NULL,
               [IsSwingArm] bit  Not NULL,
               [IsLoadScale] bit  Not NULL,
               [PresetId] Int  Not NULL
           );"
   Dim myCommand1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str1, myConn)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't select any **Database** with your code.

The database must be selected in SQL Connection function.

Comment: That is not true. It is common to select the database using the connection string, but it can also be set using the `USE` statement.

Comment: @MatSnow - With the caveat that the other database must be in the same instance as the connection string...